# powershell running as windows service giving incomplete output

Tags: windows, service

I want to run a powershell script as windows service. The script is pretty huge and takes a while to run. 
I am redirecting the output of this script as text using start-stop transcript in powershell script. When the script is ran through windows service output is not complete. Its giving me half the output.

I have created service using : 
"C:\path\to\instsrv.exe" myservice "C:\path\to\srvany.exe" then giving 
C:\path\to\powershell.exe -noprofile -File "C:\path\to\myscript.ps1" in Application in registry.

While running script through powershell console, transcript redirects full output to a file but not through service.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what is going on, but you can [setup your powershell with the free 30-day trial of AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/Apps/RunPowerShellScriptAsAService.html) to troubleshoot. Maybe you need to run in a user account?